# moving files and folders between dropboxes

Tags: dropbox

I have a personal dropbox and a work dropbox. I'm trying to move a folder from my personal dropbox to my work dropbox. If I Google this issue, I get the following page

https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/4623

which basically says that I need to connect the two, then I'll be able to drag folders between the two dropboxes. However, when I go to settings, I see that the two dropboxes are already connected, but when I try to follow the instructions on that page and drag folders from one dropbox to the other, nothing happens. I also try clicking the "Move" button, but then it only displays destinations in the current dropbox, not destinations in the other one. I'm using the latest version of Google chrome on latest version of Mac OS.

What am I doing wrong, and how do I successfully move a folder between two dropboxes?

Comment: Have you tried using the web app to share the folder between the two accounts?  Then you could use these instructions to transfer ownership before removing the original account:  https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/242

Comment: yep this works. However, it is still slightly less convenient than what the page in my original post suggests is possible

Answer (score 2):

Interesting problem.  I suggest you simply *share* your **personal** folders with your **work** folders.  Then when you get to work, it would sync up.  Once everything is in sync, when on your work Dropbox, copy your files into an unshared directory and then unshare your personal folder with your work folder.  Don't use the web interface to move files.  Use the application that Dropbox gives you to copy the files from a shared folder to an unshared folder.

Comment: Yes, that worked and does what I am trying to do. However, the instructions clearly say it's possible to simply drag folders between connected dropboxes. Is this just a huge typo, or did they write instructions for a feature that does not exist?

Comment: I don't have a business account so I really can't verify it.  It sounds like though from DropBox's suggestion is that you can connect both DropBoxes on one system, open up your File Explorer and then simply drag your files between them.  They don't mention the File Explorer however I'm assuming that is what they mean.  DropBox gives you another drive for your personal DropBox and also one for your Business Dropbox.  Have you tried this?